# Wpf Custom Control problem

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have strange problem with WPF custom control that I have made. When I drag and drop WPF custom control from toolbox to design surface I only see one border without any controls in it... I have another same WPF custom control project with same custom control and same code and when I reference that project everything works fine.

I have template in theme folder that is called DatePicker.Generic.Xaml and I have defined

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DateControls:DatePicker}" 
       TargetType="{x:Type DateControls:DatePicker}">
```

where DateControls is xml namespace of my DatePicker custom control.
I have also added

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly,
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```

in assemblyinfo file.
Can someone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check that your control code has a static constructor that calls DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata with the appropriate type arguments (it's generated for you if you add a new custom control in VS).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [ComponentResourceKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.componentresourcekey.aspx) Markup Extension.  Look at the TypeInTargetAssembly and ResourceId argument (of componentresourcekey)'s when you set the Style element.

Comment: I have look and everything seems fine. I have several times defined TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DateControls:DatePicker},ResourceId=DropDownButtonStyleKey with different ResourceId and DateControls is good namespace...